# How to Hide Button permanently after one clicked in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

**I want to hide start course button permanently after one click.** and I refresh my brower, then show me only resume button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.17"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showDiv=true" ng-show="!showDiv">Start Course</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="showDiv">Resume</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';                 
});
```

this is my [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/tAkK9dyJFkgxe9yULdRH?p=previeweview)

Comment: You would need to use `localStorage` if you want changes to persist on reload.

Comment: I am a beginner in this tech., please explain to me how I will use localStorage for the button

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check plunker: [Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XCuFkAUjMscTnsKutKV4?p=preview)

You would use something like this:

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.showDiv = false;

  $scope.getItem = function(){
    var stored = localStorage.getItem("showDiv");
    if(stored)
      $scope.showDiv = JSON.parse(stored)
  }

  $scope.saveItem = function(){
    localStorage.setItem("showDiv", true)
  }

  $scope.getItem();

});
```

And HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showDiv=true; saveItem();" ng-show="!showDiv">Start Course</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use localStorage use following steps.

1.install ngStorage in your app

```
npm i ng-storage
```

2.in your module

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngStorage'
])
```

3.inject in your controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    if ($localStorage.showDiv == true) {
        $scope.showDiv = true;
    }else{
        $scope.showDiv = false;
    }
    $scope.hideStart = function(){
       $scope.showDiv = true;
       $localStorage.showDiv = true;
    }
});
```

4.in html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="hideStart()" ng-if="!showDiv">Start Course</button>
```